# 2D array and its transpose

Tags: java, arrays

so i just finished my program but the problem is every time i enter the elements i want my array to be for example if i enter a 3X2 array it prints out a 3X3 array and its transpose. now it works great except that when it outputs the correct output i get an outof bounds error at the end of the output.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Prog2c {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int userChoice;
        int userChoice2;



        System.out.println("Program 2c, Christian Villa, masc1854");
        System.out.print("please enter the first dimension of your array: ");
        userChoice = in.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Please enter the second dimension of your array: ");
        userChoice2 = in.nextInt();



        int[][] list = randArray(userChoice,userChoice2);
        printList(list);



        if(list.length > 0)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
            {
                for(int j = 0; j < list.length; j++)
                {
                    System.out.print(list[j][i] + "  ");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        }

    }


    /*--------------------------------------------------------------
    Method name: randArray
    Description: Creates a random array of n number of elements that is assigned by the user
    input:    a double array
    Output:        none
    Returns:      a randomly generated array 
    ----------------------------------------------------------------
    */
    public static int[][] randArray(int userChoice,int userChoice2)
    {
        int[][] list = new int[userChoice][userChoice2];
        Random random = new Random();
        for(int i = 0; i < userChoice; i++)
            for(int j = 0; j < userChoice2; j++)
        {
               list[i][j] = random.nextInt((99-10)+1)+10; 
        }
        return list;
     }
    /*--------------------------------------------------------------
    Method name: printList
    Description: Prints the contents of an integer 2D array.
    input:    an integer 2D array
    Output:       display an integer 2D array
    Returns:      none
    ----------------------------------------------------------------
    */
    public static void printList(int[][] list)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < list.length; j++)
            {
                System.out.print(list[i][j]);
                System.out.print("  ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

Comment: The first steps to getting any problem fixed: 1) What is supposed to happen? 2) What happens instead?

Comment: so it asks the user to enter what kind of array he/she wnats for example it'll ask the dimensions so i would enter a 3X2 and the it would print out that 3X2 array with randomly generated numbers and it would also print out the transpose of taht same array but in my program if i were to enter 3X2 it out puts a 3X3

Comment: Problem is in `for(int j = 0; j < list.length; j++)` You should compare to `list[i].length`

Comment: when i tried comparing to list[i].length i seem to have gotten an out of bounds

Comment: it prints out the correct output but i get an out of bounds error hmm

Comment: i just added a small edit  for(int j = 0; j < list.length; j++) which works great but i get Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
 at Prog2c.main(Prog2c.java:34)

Comment: You forgot to change one more `for` loop just after `printList(list);`

Comment: when i change it there   the program doesnt finish outputtung and gets an error

Comment: Check the answer given below.. then you understand which `for` loop I am talking about

Comment: so far with that fix im able to get it working but error still appears hmm

Comment: @laune - Agree and this is exactly why I **didn't** do it.  I merely suggested it in comments way before you posted your answer. Look at revisions.

Comment: @ChrisV Indicating where you get which error would help.

Comment: @ChrisV Don't ever edit questions to fix errors in the posted code. All comments and answers are instantly turned into nonsense. This is very bad form for SO.

Comment: @laune actually im not quite sure thing is it print outs my matrix and then it prints out the transpose of it, how its suppose to, but then at the end it just says its out of bounds ???

Comment: @PM77-1 Sorry. It was ChrisV.

Comment: 44  54  
14  96  
77  90  

44  14  77  
54  96  90  
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
 at Prog2c.main(Prog2c.java:34)

Comment: Did you fix the loop to print the transpose? Please check carefully: outer loop i to list[0].length, inner loop j to list.length and access list[j][i]. - If it happens after printing the transposed you must have more code that's not in your Q.

Comment: Thank you so much now the error is gone. just one question is it possible to explain why the list[0].length was necessary?

Comment: If you have int[2][3] list, then the regular matrix is 2 x 3 =  list.length x list[0].length but the transposed is 3x2, i.e., list[0].length x list.length. These values are essential for limiting the variables iterating rows and columns. list[0].length is the best choice, but the length of any other *existing* row would work as well since all rows have equal length (when you create the array using new int[x][y]).

Answer (score 1):

In the main program,
to print the matrix you can omit the if. The first index is the row index, the second for the columns. Use the length of a row array to print rows.

```
void printMatrix( int[][] list ){
    for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < list[i].length; j++){
            System.out.print(list[i][j] + "  ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

To print the transpose, you exchange rows and columns:

```
   for(int i = 0; i < list[0].length; i++){
       for(int j = 0; j < list.length; j++){
             System.out.print(list[j][i] + "  ");
       }
       System.out.println();
   }
```

But it is probably better to compute the transposed matrix:

```
int[][] transpose( int[][] list ){
    int[][] t = new int[list[0].length][list.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
       for(int j = 0; j < list[0].length; j++){
           t[j][i] = list[i][j];
       }
   }
   return t;
}
```

Now you can reuse print:

```
printMatrix( list );
int[][] listT = transpose( list );
printMatrix( listT );
```

Comment: Hello...User wants the transpose of the matrix. Your code is printing same

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
 at Prog2c.main(Prog2c.java:34)

Comment: thats the error i get but it does output the correct output but still gives me that error

Comment: with that solution works great but just not sure why it  gives me the error

Comment: @AJ. Thanks for the alert. I lost that completely, trying to come to grips with sudden changes in the Q.